# How Can I Change The Background Color Of A Button Using Tkinter On MacOs Big Sur

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, background

## Expected Behavior

I should get an output like this:

[image]

## Observed behavior

What I got:

[image]

## The Code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def my_click():
    my_label = Label(root, text='Look! I clicked a button!')
    my_label.pack()


my_button = Button(root, text='Click Me!', command=my_click, bg='#6d35e6', fg='#0000ff')
my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

### Update On The Code

I'm using an attribute called `highlightbackground` instead of `bg` for the background. You can check the comment that I made for further details.

## Version Info

```
System Os: MacOs Big Sur 11.3 (LTS)
Python Version: 3.9.4 (LTS)
Tkniter Version: 8.6 (LTS)
Code Editor: PyCharm CE Community 2021.1.1 (LTS)
```

Comment: Just saying that on `Windows 10` + `tcl 8.6`, I get a purple button with blue text inside it. So the problem must come from MacOS.

Comment: @TheLizzard Yeah, I know that. I'm just asking about MacOs.

Comment: Have you tried using `"purple"` instead of `"#6d35e6"`? It might work but I don't own any devises that have MacOS

Comment: I too don't use Mac. Can someone test who uses mac? Also thank you for your detailed question.

Comment: You can't change the colors of buttons on OSX.

Comment: @BryanOakley Are they fully controlled by the OS? Do you mind writing an answer. I am very interested by this question

Comment: @TheLizzard Whenever I do that I get something like this: https://gist.github.com/CodeWithAnish/9992032c922c274fb636bf66bb4cd7ee (I sent a link to GitHub since I didn't know how to attach an image. You'll find the image in the comments btw.)

Comment: **Update** 

I actually hound an attribute called "highlightbackground" which did change the background color but as soon as I press the button or moved the window around it would look something like this:


[Link To The Image](https://gist.github.com/CodeWithAnish/9992032c922c274fb636bf66bb4cd7ee) (You'll find the image in the comments)

Comment: @CodeWithAnish have you tried setting `activebackground`? If that doesn't work why setting `highlightcolor`

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried that and it just removed the background entirely, I think that might not be a parameter option.

Comment: If you really want to change the colour of the button on macOS and can use an external library then you can try [tkmacosx](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/).

Comment: @Saad **THANKS ALOT** I read the documentation and it worked flawlessly. Thanks! 